# Transactions with multiple connections (MySql, C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, connection

I'd like to ask a question. I've been trying to find some information regarding transactions with multiple connections, but I haven't been able to find any good source of information.

Now for what I'm trying to do. I have code that looks like this:

```
using (var Connection1 = m_Db.CreateConnection())
using (var Connection2 = m_Db.CreateConnection())
{
    Connection1.DoRead(..., (IDataReader Reader) =>
    {
        // Do stuff
        Connection2.DoWrite(...);
        Connection2.DoRead(..., (IDataReader Reader) =>
        {
            // Do more stuff
            using (var Connection3 = m_Db.CreateConnection())
            {
                Connection3.DoWrite(...);
                Connection3.Commit(); // Is this even right?
            }
        });
    });

    Connection1.DoRead(..., (IDataReader) =>
    {
        // Do yet more stuff
    });
    Connection1.Commit();
    Connection2.Commit();
}
```

Each CreateConnection creates a new transaction using MySqlConnection::BeginTransaction. The CreateConnection method creates a Connection object which wraps a MySqlConnection. The DoRead function executes some SQL, and disposes the IDataReader when done.

Every Connection will do a Rollback when disposed.

Now for some notes:

- I have ONE server with multiple databases.
- I am running MySql server with InnoDB databases.
- I am doing both reads and writes to these databases.
- For performance reasons and not to mess up the database, I am using transactions.
- The code is (at least, for now) entirely serial. There are NO concurrent threads. All inserts and queries are done in serial fashion.
- I use multiple connections to the database because a read or write is not allowed while another read is in progress (basically the reader object has not yet been disposed).
- I basically want every connection to see all changes. So for example, after Connection 3 does some writes, Connection 1 should see those. But the data should be in the transaction and not written to the database (yet).

Now, as for my questions:

- Does this work? Will everything ONLY be committed only once the last Commit function is called? Should I use another approach?
- Is this right? Is my approach completely and utterly wrong and silly?
- Any drawbacks? Especially regarding performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, it seems no one knows. But that's okay.

For now, I just went with the method of just using one connection and reading all the results into a List>, then closing the reader, thereby avoiding the problem of having to use multiple connections.

Might there be performance problems? Maybe, but it's better than having to deal with uncertainty and deadlocks.